# modify html after mithrill component loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, mithril.js

This is a piece of my vdom

```
m('.w-row', _.map(ctrl.posts(), (post) => {
                        return m('.w-col.w-col-4.col-blog-post',
                            [
                                m(`a.link-hidden.fontweight-semibold.fontsize-base.u-marginbottom-10[href="${post[2][1]}"][target=\'__blank\']`, post[0][1]),
                                m('.fontsize-smaller.fontcolor-secondary.u-margintop-10', m.trust(`${post[1][1]}`))
                            ]
                        );
                    })),
```

In the part `m.trust('${post[1][1]}')` I get a part of html. What I want to do with that html is add `target _blank` for each link in that html. I have tried adding `config` inside the `trust` but that function is not executing. Any idea how i can do that.

Here is my js to add target _blank to the html

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('medium-feed-item');
div[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
div[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: I think that the `config` function should he provided as an option of ` m('.fontsize-smaller.fontcolor-secondary.u-margintop-10')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `config` call in the node above the `m.trust`:

```
m('.w-row', _.map(ctrl.posts(), post =>
  m('.w-col.w-col-4.col-blog-post',
    m(`a.link-hidden.fontweight-semibold.fontsize-base.u-marginbottom-10[href="${post[2][1]}"][target=\'__blank\']`, post[0][1]),
      m('.fontsize-smaller.fontcolor-secondary.u-margintop-10', {
        config(el){
          _.map(el.querySelectorAll('a:not([target=__blank])'), el =>
            el.setAttribute('target', '__blank')
          )
        }
      },
        m.trust(`${post[1][1]}`)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: `a:not([href=__blank])` looks very wrong. There is (was) pending edit by @Raaz trying to fix it, but I don't think fix was correct (and should not be made as edit anyway - should be comment). Most likely should be something like  `target=...`, same for `setAttribute`.